Planes on Curves
My blend works, but when I wanted to respond to this post "Geometry Node: How would I convert a series of Curve Lines into a series of Planes", I proceeded using an empirical approach.


First I don't understand why the even faces and the odd faces are separated?
So a part of this blend is still very strange to me.
For what I know, when the number "Count" is odd the first face off the odd faces go directly from the start of the curve to the end. The second line of nodes (just under) is here to fix this problem. But as I tested lot of numbers, finally I came up with a solution, that doesn't mean that I understand how it works... I wish you can explain to me what I have done here:

And I have a second question is it possible to reorder the faces?

Thanks for your help.
Here is the blend:

Edit:
After the answer of Joel Reid, I will try to simplify and narrow down this question to a more simple problem and a more simple blend.
In fact my problem is to understand why those nodes produce only the evens faces and not the odds ones.


I hope this formulation is more likely to be understood, I am perfectly conscious that is a very different problem, and I am sorry for that. Thank you for your help.


Could you expand on the "empirical approach" in plain english ? I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, nor what these 10+ math nodes are doing.

@Lutzi, thank you, the purpose of these nodes is to order the indexes of each point of odd faces... I can't say more I don't understand what I have done... Sory.

What do you mean "order the indexes of each point of odd faces" ? Is your screenshot what you are trying to achieve, or an issue you have ? Please explain your goal clearly. I still have no idea what you want and where is the issue.

@Lutzi, Sorry I will try to be more clear and will edit my post. By "empirical approach" I mean that I have tested each step to see how it works (and find solutions) but for exemple I don't understand why the odd and even faces are separated... I thought that the simple Store Named Attribute Pos-Even was enough, it's not..

What?
We can examine the setup and perhaps gain some insight into what it is "trying" to accomplish.
In your Odd Face Index Calculation frame, let's follow the data left-to-right…

…and interrogate each in turn for "what is this node's output, conceptually?"

Truncated Modulo
This node uses the [Bezier Segment's, Curve's Points, Point Cloud's] Point Count (hereafter: "c"). The node's output Value is c mod 2.
Switch
A 0 or 1 subtrahend determined by c's oddness.
Add
The greatest odd int ≤ c
Subtract
The second-greatest odd int ≤ c



Add
Pardon my syntax from here forward, where curly braces indicate the two possible values.
{is c even? → 2c - 4,
 is c odd? →  2c - 2}
Index
"Points of Reference" Curve To Points, point index field
Subtract
index - 2c - {4,2}
Multiply
2c
Subtract
index - 2c - {6,4}
Subtract
2c - 4
Greater Than or Equal
bool answering, is 9's "index - 2c - {6,4}" ≥ 2 ?
Add
index - {10,8}



Switch




combined case
Output value
simplified




c even and index - 2c - 6 ≥ 2
index - 2c - 6



c odd and index - 2c - 4 ≥ 2
index - 2c - 4



c even and index - 2c - 6 < 2
index - 2c - 6 + 2c - 4
index - 10


c odd and index - 2c - 4 < 2
index - 2c - 4 + 2c - 4
index - 8



Why?
That node tree is many things; "working", reducible, intractable, baffling…
The above was all easy enough to work out. But then what does, say, "the index 6 less than double the input count of the current index" across the realized curve's points field mean to you? You're the user of this node arrangement.
I love Geometry Nodes, and love messing about with them as much as the next Blender-er, but I humbly submit that this method of throwing nodes at a problem is a horrible way to work and clearly no way to learn. If you're borrowing and adapting someone else's complex method of accomplishing something, you should…
go back and study what exactly they're accomplishing,
borrow the parts you understand,
adapt it only with new methods and nodes and workflows you also understand.
I hope the above breakdowns perhaps gave you some insight you can use to push forward. I think this is all that can be done with your question as asked, as Blender Stack Exchange is not for requesting tutorials and project autopsies, but for pointed technical questions and solving of clear problems—which is frankly not a fitting description for the situation you're in. Please ask another question if you reduce your tree to a clear technical question. Good luck.

[mods, I plead with you not to delete this answer for it's non-answer-ness and prose… GN node spaghetti is a common Blender problem and I think this is the "answer" this unanswerable question warrants.]

Has been acknowledged! Essentially agree with you too. Many thanks for your contribution!

@Joel Reid First thank you very much for your precise work. As I read you I can’t disagree that is an unanswerable question. And I am sorry for that. But please, let me try to narrow down what is my problem here. I will edit and let the previous question as it is in order to keep your answer as the most correct one. Once again thank You.

The answer was so evident that’s I am ashamed (as I should be), the first face is fixed on the 0, 1, 2 and 3 points then the second plan one 4, 5, 6, 7 points and so on…
So there is no plan between the points 2, 3, 4 ,5: there is no odd faces. With just another Sample Index plug on indexes plus 2, it makes the good indexes for the odd faces.


I am very sorry for the time you lost on this question. Thank you.

No time lost. There are several useful patterns in those trees (as you've seen—they work!). Even the point-count * 2 stuff makes sense… it's doubling the curve then working on it, and so forth. Alternating faces just falls out of this approach too. Glad you've cracked it—cheers!
